# pipe the output of `aws glue list-jobs` to `aws glue start-job-run`

Tags: bash, amazon-web-services, powershell, aws-cli

How do I pipe the output of `aws glue list-jobs...` to `aws glue start-job-run` in powershell and bash?

Ex. something like:

`aws glue list-jobs --tags name=something (magic here) | aws glue start-job-run (magic here)`

This being a solution to the problem: quickly starting multiple jobs using the universal aws cli.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Make the `aws glue list-jobs` call output the job names as text (`--output text`).
- Using `%` (a built-in alias of the [`ForEach-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/foreach-object) cmdlet), pass each job name to `aws glue start-job-run` via the `--job-name` parameter and the [automatic `$_` variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Automatic_Variables#_).

```
# % is short for ForEach-Object
aws glue list-jobs --tags name=something --output text | 
  % { aws glue start-job-run --job-name $_ }
```

Update: You report that you ended up using the following, relying on the default output format, JSON:

```
# % is short for ForEach-Object
aws glue list-jobs --tags name=something  | 
  ConvertFrom-Json |
  Select-Object -ExpandProperty JobNames |
  % { aws glue start-job-run --job-name $_ }
```

Comment: Thank you, eventually i ended up wth `aws glue list-jobs --tags name=something  | ConvertFrom-Json | Select-Object -ExpandProperty JobNames | % {aws glue start-job-run --job-name $_}`

Comment: Thanks, @ams1 - I can't verify it myself, but doesn't my command do the same? Or are the names not output line by line with `--output text`?